# Is there a left hereditary ring which is not right semihereditary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra

I know that if such an example exists, then it cannot be left or right noetherian.

Reminders:

- A left hereditary ring is one in which all left ideals are projective as modules.
- A right semihereditary ring is one in which all finitely generated right ideals are projective as modules.

Comment: Hm, good question. At present [DaRT does not have such an example](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=70l&L=71r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opening paragraph of

> Small, Lance W. "Semihereditary rings." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society 73.5 (1967): 656-658.

says

> In [7] the author constructed an example of a ring which was even right hereditary (all right ideals are projective) yet not left semihereditary.

Citation 7 is

> Small, Lance W. "Hereditary rings." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 55.1 (1966): 25-27. [link](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.55.1.25)

Comment: Just googled `"right hereditary" "not left semihereditary"`

Comment: I could include the details of the construction but the actual justifications for why it is what it is are really too involved to copy, so I think the references are the best way to go.